# Spring @ActionMapping syntax for Portlets

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, portlet

I know this works where the url contains the parameter 'deleteItem=6'

```
@ActionMapping(params="deleteItem")
public void deleteItem(@ModelAttribute("items") Items items, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam int deleteItem) throws Exception {
    items.getItems().remove(deleteItem);
    ...
}
```

but can I do something like this (use the *value* of the deleteItem parameter:

```
@ActionMapping(params="deleteItem={idx}")
public void deleteItem(@ModelAttribute("items") Items items, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam int idx) throws Exception {
    items.getItems().remove(idx);
    ...
}
```

No biggie, it's that the code is more readable because it shows that the parameter value is an index.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use a dynamic param as a binding name like this `@ActionMapping(params="deleteItem={idx}")` because Spring Portlet MVC needs to bind a method to an action with a unique name.

Your first snippet is correct.

Comment: Oh well. If it can bind to @ActionMapping(params="deleteItem") which means 'bind if param named deleteItem is present', you would think it could go the extra step.